# How do I deploy my react app into my FTP

Tags: node.js, reactjs, deployment, ftp

I used create-react-app to set everything up.

I was able to get a live version of it up on surge.

I now want to add it to my personal website that's hosted by Bluehost.

I need to upload it using an FTP Client.

https://codingforkids.us/projects/joesprojects/ravenous/

This is the result of running npm run build and placing the contents of the build folder into the FTP client. The page is blank.

Here's the app on Surge: http://ambiguous-afternoon.surge.sh/

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple 404s for the css,js files your trying to server. Make sure the files are available on the host, and whether they are can be statically served.

[image: 404]

Answer (score 0):

The most likely problem is that you need to add an .htaccess file into the public directory prior to doing your build.

[Check out the React article on deployment](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/deployment)

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
```

Also ensure you've set your URL in the manifest.json (also in public)

You may also have to do a hard refresh of your site.